# android - Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

I have an error code that I do not have a resolver, and I looked for several ways here in `stackoverflow` but I did not succeed.

the error that is displayed:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                           at
>   softcode.tattostudio.BudgetFragment$1GetImage.onPostExecute(BudgetFragment.java:250)
>                                                                           at
>   softcode.tattostudio.BudgetFragment$1GetImage.onPostExecute(BudgetFragment.java:240)

Basic the lines that give the error are:

```
private void getImage(String urlToImage){
    class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap> {  //This line is 240

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            imgvShowTattoIMG.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //This line is 250
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url = null;
            Bitmap image = null;

            String urlToImage = params[0];
            try {
                url = new URL(urlToImage);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;
        }
    }
    GetImage gi = new GetImage();
    gi.execute(urlToImage);
}
```

Anyone have any idea what it could be? Need to post the full code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone have any idea what it could be?

`imgvShowTattoIMG` is `null`.

Beyond that, I strongly recommend that you use an existing image-loading library (e.g., Picasso, Glide) rather than implementing your own code for that.

Comment: but is not null, was declared as '' ImageView imgvShowTattoIMG = view.findViewById(R.id.imgvShowTattoIMG); ''

Comment: @JhonathanCandeu: "but is not null" -- according to your stack trace, it is. "was declared as" -- then perhaps `view` does not contain a widget with the ID of `imgvShowTattoIMG`.

Comment: the ImageView widget is in my layout.xml, I honestly do not understand how it can be null if I declare it by id

Comment: @JhonathanCandeu: "the ImageView widget is in my layout.xml" -- perhaps `view` is not coming from that layout resource.

Comment: in this same context I edit other textview of the same layout, the problem lies in that imageview that the code says to be null

Comment: @JhonathanCandeu: You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you show your layout and your code that uses the layout.

Comment: I can understand the code, what happens is that the inflated view does not contain the widget, it is in another view inflated in the same context, but if I inflate view 2 and declare my widget, the error will continue because my "getImage "is on view 1. Do you understand what I mean? How can I declare my widget from another layout in the same inflated view?

Comment: @JhonathanCandeu: "Do you understand what I mean?" -- no, sorry.

Comment: I posted another question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50195037/android-how-to-declare-a-widget-from-another-layout