# android - how to declare a widget from another layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a fragment layout that contains a class, but it needs to edit an imageview that is in another layout fragment. Example:

```
public class LayoutFragment extends Fragment {
private ImageView imageView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView); // this imageview is not fragment_layout, he is in fragment_layout2

    addChild();

    return view;
}

private void addChild() {
    LayoutInflater inflates = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    int id = R.layout.dynamic_layout_budget;
    LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) inflates.inflate(id, null, false);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    layout.addView(relativeLayout);
      }
}
```

but if I do this, an error of type "attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference"

How could I manipulate this imageview that is in another fragment layout?

Comment: "How could I manipulate this imageview that is in another fragment layout?" -- most likely, you don't. One fragment should not be manipulating another fragment's widgets. Perhaps there should be only one fragment, rather than two. Or, perhaps this code should simply be part of the other fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because you are paying null as a parent in inflater.

So instead of passing null in parent of

`LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) inflates.inflate(id, null, false);`

try passing a view in that like

`LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) inflates.inflate(id, layout, false);`

But from your code I'm not sure that what's the value of `layout` variable inside add method.